# display flex esta com um comportamento diferente no google chrome

Tags: html, css

Olá, espero que alguém possa me ajudar nesse problema. Desenvolvi apenas o template, a programação php não sou eu que estou fazendo. Aqui esta ocorrendo muitos espaços nos itens.

http://dpmeducacaonovo.teraware.info/home

Estou alinhando os cards com display: flex. Funciona no Firefox, mas no google Chrome esta dando muitos espaços. Minha intenção é que todos os cards tenham o mesmo tamanho, mas o conteúdo deve ser dinâmico, pois os títulos tem tamanhos diferentes. O mesmo esta ocorrendo no side bar. 
O mais estranho é que com apenas o template, sem a programação php, o site fica bem tanto no Chrome quanto no firefox.
http://geekyweb.byethost11.com/

Se visualizar no Firefox, o primeiro link não ocorre o problema. O que pode ser? Erro de estrutura no html ou é erro de template? E como pode ser erro de template, se no segundo link abre nos dois navegadores e não ocorre este problema? Estou muito perdido amigos, alguém me da uma luz amiga. Por favor!!!
O problema não ocorre com o código html.

o segundo link é apenas html o sem a codificação php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc vai resolver o problema assim,

Tira o `height:100%` da classe `.space-between`

E na `div` pai de `.space-between` vc vai colocar a classe `d-flex`, vai ficar assim `<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-12 col-md-4 col-md-4 d-flex">`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado hugocsl! você me ajudou muito. te desejo muita saúde e prosperidade. O mundo precisa de pessoas como você. Que Deus te ilumine nessa vida e muito Obrigado novamente!

Comment: @Daniel_php_programer agradeço pelas palavras e fico feliz em ter ajudado. Sucesso com o projeto, abs ;)